# How to wait in bash till a shell script is finished?

Tags: bash, wait, sleep

right now I'm using this script for a program:

```
export FREESURFER_HOME=$HOME/freesurfer
source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh

cd /home/ubuntu/fastsurfer
datadir=/home/ubuntu/moya/data
fastsurferdir=/home/ubuntu/moya/output
mkdir -p $fastsurferdir/logs # create log dir for storing nohup output log (optional)

while read p ; do
  echo $p
  nohup ./run_fastsurfer.sh --t1 $datadir/$p/orig.nii \
                            --parallel --threads 16 --sid $p --sd $fastsurferdir > $fastsurferdir/logs/out-${p}.log &
  sleep 3600s
done < /home/ubuntu/moya/data/subjects-list.txt
```

Instead of using `sleep 3600s`, as the program needs around an hour, I'd like to use `wait` until all processes (several PIDS) are finished.
If this is the right way, can you tell me how to do that?

BR Alex

Answer (score 1):

`wait` will wait for all background processes to finish (see `help wait`). So all you need is to run `wait` after creating all of the background processes.

Answer (score 0):

This may be more than what you are asking for but I figured I would provide some methods for controlling the number of threads you want to have running at once. I find that I always want to limit the number for various reasons.

**Explaination**

The following will limit concurrent threads to max_threads running at one time. I am also using the main design pattern so we have a main that runs the script with a function run_jobs that handles the calling and waiting. I read all of $p into an array, then traverse that array as we launch threads. It will either launch a thread up to 4 or wait 5 seconds, once there are at least one less than four it will start another thread. When finished it waits for any remaining to be done. If you want something more simplistic I can do that as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export FREESURFER_HOME=$HOME/freesurfer
source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh

typeset max_threads=4
typeset subjects_list="/home/ubuntu/moya/data/subjects-list.txt"
typeset subjectsArray

run_jobs() {
    local child="$$"
    local num_children=0
    local i=0
    while [[ 1 ]] ; do
        num_children=$(ps --no-headers -o pid --ppid=$child | wc -w) ; ((num_children-=1))
        echo "Children: $num_children"
        if [[ ${num_children} -lt ${max_threads} ]] ;then
            if [ $i -lt ${#subjectsArray[@]} ] ;then
                ((i+=1))
                # RUN COMMAND HERE &
                ./run_fastsurfer.sh --t1 $datadir/${subjectsArray[$i]}/orig.nii \
                                --parallel --threads 16 --sid ${subjectsArray[$i]} --sd $fastsurferdir 
            fi
        fi
        sleep 10
    done
    wait
}


main() {
    cd /home/ubuntu/fastsurfer
    datadir=/home/ubuntu/moya/data
    fastsurferdir=/home/ubuntu/moya/output
    mkdir -p $fastsurferdir/logs # create log dir for storing nohup output log (optional)

    mapfile -t subjectsArray < ${subjects_list}
    run_jobs
}

main
```

Note: I did not run this code since you have not provided enough information to actually do so.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After changing a bit, there's one error, in ./run_fastsurfer.sh --t1 `$datadir/${subjects_list[$i]}/orig.nii \
                                --parallel --threads 16 --sid ${subjects_list[$i]} --sd ` the subjects list is not recognised and  I get a console error `...(/home/ubuntu/moya/data//orig.nii) could not be found.`

Comment: Hey I subjects_list is supposed to be subjectsArray... that is probably  the issue. I updated the script above to what it should be.   You can also confirm that the array is being set correctly with adding a echo "${subjectsArray[@]}" after the 'mapfile line. If there is an issue you can read into an array differently like this:  while IFS= read -r p ;do
 subjectsArray+=($p)
done < "${subjects_list}"

Comment: If you want you can give your code and I can review it locally.